# Strongly coupled electromagnetic force

Tags: electromagnetism, strong-force

What would be defining about a strongly coupled electromagnetic force? Would it mean that separating two oppositely charged particles makes another particle-antiparticle pair, rather than continuing to separate the particles? Would it make the electromagnetic force "hadronic", in a sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you call a 'strongly coupled' force. If you simply use a larger value for the coupling constant, then there is not much reason to believe a lot will change qualitatively, except that perturbative methods will get worse. [The wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_constant) on this topic may give you a good point to start looking for a more specific question or to refine your thoughts.

Alternatively, you could be talking about simply defining a 'strong force' that acts on electromagnetic charges in the same way the *actual* strong force acts on color charge. This would, of course, yield a 'hadronic'-like force. However, that is **simply not what we see in nature**. Other than that, there is not much against studying such a thing, if one would be inclined to do so ;)